# List.Contains is not working as hoped

Tags: c#, list, iequalitycomparer

If I have an object of type `MyBull` and a `List<MyBull> orig`:

```
// Just an example
MyBull x = getMeTheObjectWithIdFromDB(9);

orig.add(x);

// Again same? data object
MyBull y = getMeTheObjectWithIdFromDB(9);
```

Why is this false then?

```
// This is false, even though all the properties
// of x and y are the same.
orig.Contains<MyBull>(y);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default objects will expose reference based equality.  If you want custom rules, such as equality based on id fields, you need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods.

Comment: This answer scored me another point in my "answer-a-C#-question-by-giving-a-Java-answer" game! :) Although I don't have much C# experience, the inner Java developer instantly blurted out "he forgot to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`!" ;)

Answer (score 8):

If you can use LINQ then you can

```
class Vessel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var vessels = new List<Vessel>() { new Vessel() { id = 4711, name = "Millennium Falcon" } };

var ship = new Vessel { id = 4711, name = "Millencolin" };

if (vessels.Any(vessel => vessel.id == ship.id))
    Console.Write("There can be only one!");
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because the MyBull instances are being compared by reference.  From the point of view from .NET, x and y are both *different instances* and therefore not Equal.

In order to get around this you will have to [override the Equals and GetHashCode methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(VS.71).aspx) (which means you should probably implement [`IEquatable<MyBull>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) and override the == and != operators too).

Answer (score 3):

Does your MyBull object implement `IEquatable<T>.Equals`? This method will determine the equality of two objects

**requested by OP**

Your MyBull class would implement IEquatable

```
public class MyBull : IEquatable<MyBull>
```

and then you would need to override the `Equals` method

```
public bool Equals(MyBull theOtherMyBull)
```

As David Neale mentions below, this is best used when you're comparing objects of the same type--which you are. Overriding Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode will work too.

Comment: From MSDN (IEquatable<T>.Equals Method) - Indicates whether the current object is equal to another object of the same type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx

Comment: That appears to be what is requested--using a generic List<MyBull>. @David Neale: sorry, misread your comment. It is simply clarification of my remark on "equality of two objects"