# List.Contains<T> always giving false

Tags: c#, list, hash, overriding, equals

It seems that this problem has already been encountered by quite a few people:

[List not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959581/list-contains-is-not-working-as-hoped)

[Contains always giving false](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/686419-problem-using-list-contains)

So I saw the answers and tried to implement the override of Equals and of GetHashCode but there seems that I am coding something wrong.

This is the situation: I have a list of Users(Class), each user has a List and a Name property, the list property contains licenses. I am trying to do a

```
         if (!users.Contains(currentUser))
```

but it is not working as expected. And this is the code I did to override the Equals and GetHashCode:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as User);
    }


    public bool Equals(User otherUser)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(otherUser, null))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, otherUser))
            return true;

        return this._userName.Equals(otherUser.UserName) && 
               this._licenses.SequenceEqual<string>(otherUser.Licenses);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        if (!_licenses.Any() && !_userName.Equals(""))
        {
            unchecked
            {
                foreach (string str in Licenses)
                {
                    hash *= 7;
                    if (str != null) hash = hash + str.GetHashCode();
                }
                hash = (hash * 7) + _userName.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
        return hash;
    }
```

thank you for your suggestions and help in advance!

EDIT 1:

this is the code where I am doing the List.Contains, I am trying to see if the list already contains certain user, if not then add the user that isn't there. The Contains only works the first time, when currentUser changes then the User inside the list changes to the current user maybe this is a problem that is unrelated to the equals, any ideas?

```
        if (isIn)
        {
            if (!listOfLicenses.Contains(items[3]))
                listOfLicenses.Add(items[3]);

            if (!users.Contains(currentUser))
            {
                User user2Add = new User();
                user2Add.UserName = currentUser.UserName;
                users.Add(user2Add);
                userIndexer++;
            }

            if (users[userIndexer - 1].UserName.Equals(currentUser.UserName))
            {
                users[userIndexer - 1].Licenses.Add(items[3]);
            }
            result.Rows.Add();
        }
```

Comment: Does the list of Licenses change? Does the `_userName` change?

Comment: Have you stepped through in a debugger to see which line is producing the incorrect results?

Comment: I would delete the `if (!_licenses.Any() && !_userName.Equals(""))` because it's quite useless, but other than this, it seems to be ok. Are you sure your `Licenses` are in the same order?

Comment: what do you mean? I go through a log file and the currentUser constantly changes while StreamReading the file. For some reason the Contains only works once (the first time) then when currentUser changes the inside of the user list changes aswell. I guess this is not very clear so I'll post the corresponding code in an edit.

Comment: @L.B i dont understand what you mean can you explain further? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one problem with your hash code - if *either* there are no licences *or* the username is empty, you're ignoring the other component. I'd rewrite it as:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 31 + _userName.GetHashCode();
        foreach (string licence in Licences)
        {
            hash = hash * 31 + licences.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Shorter and simpler. It doesn't matter if you use the hash code of the empty string, or if you iterate over an empty collection.

That said, I'd have expected the previous code to work anyway. Note that it's *order sensitive* for the licences... oh, and `List<T>` won't use `GetHashCode` anyway. (You should absolutely override it appropriately, but it won't be the cause of the error.)

It would really help if you could show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - I strongly suspect that you'll find it's actually a problem with your test data.

Comment: Very good suggestion, I will try to make it separately in a new project and will keep you posted.

Comment: I am rather unable to make a short but complete program since that involves probably making an almost the same project again. I think it has to do with it being order sensitive, Do you know how can I make it order insensitive? :)

Comment: @Joze: Why would it involve creating the same project again? It just needs the User class and a tiny console app to create two users who you think should be equal but aren't. As for the order sensitivity - if these are meant to be *sets* of licences, then I would suggest keeping them in a `HashSet<string>` - you can then use the `SetEquals` method.

Comment: Okay the problem seems to be solved and it was rather with the license order I'm not sure though. Thank you very much for your help and time in any case!

Comment: @Joze: You should really decide how you want to consider the collection of licences. Some options: always sorted; arbitrary order but it's important; arbitrary unimportant order (a set). Then you can use the right collection for your needs. (You should also consider whether you want to allow duplicates.)

Comment: I see, well the order really doesn't matter and about the duplicates I have to count them later so I will allow them until counted and then delete them... I don't know the advantages I can get with a set since the list is for now working well... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After `users[userIndexer - 1].Licenses.Add(items[3])` , `users[userIndexer - 1]` is not the same user anymore. You have changed the Licences which is used in equality comparison(`in User.Equals`).

--EDIT
See below code

```
public class Class
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        User u1 = new User("1");
        User u2 = new User("1");
        Console.WriteLine(u1.Equals(u2));
        u2.Lic = "2";
        Console.WriteLine(u1.Equals(u2));
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Lic;        
    public User(string lic)
    {
        this.Lic = lic;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (obj as User).Lic == Lic;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh Now I get it thank you, I'll check this if it influences it.

Comment: The thing is that I am adding the License only if the UserName is the same which to me makes sense. It doesn't matter if the user is not the same (with license difference) what is important is that their Username is the same so that the new license can be added instead of a totally new user. Do you have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Just comparing names in `Equals` function?

Answer (score 0):

You need you implement Equals and GetHashcode for the `License` class, otherwise SequenceEqual will not work.

Comment: There is no License class. License is a common string. What can I use if I can't use SequenceEqual?

Comment: Oh, Then it should work fine, only thing I can think of is if the order of licenses is wrong. I recommend the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Does your class implement `IEquatable<User>`? From your equality methods it appears it does but just checking.

The documentation for `List.Contains` states that:

> This method determines equality by using the default equality
>   comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the
>   IEquatable(T).Equals method for T (the type of values in the list)

Comment: Yes I do. I do it all in the User class. User : IEquatable<User> good point though forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to make sure that the value returned by `GetHashCode` never ever ever changes for a specific instance of an object. If the value changes then lists and dictionaries won't work correctly.

Think of `GetHashCode` as "GetPrimaryKey". You would not change the primary key of a user record in a database if someone added a new license to the user. Likewise you mustn't change the `GetHashCode`.

It appears from your code that you are changing the licenses collection and you're using that to calculate your hash code. So that is probably causing your issue.

Now, it is perfectly legitimate to use a constant value for every hash code you produce - you could just return `42` for every instance, for example. This will force calling `Equals` to determine if two objects are equal or not. All that having distinct hash codes does is short circuits the need to call `Equals`.

If the `_userName` field doesn't change then just return its hash code and see it that works.