# How to find (and remove) a nested object from a List

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

hope someone can help. I have an object:

```
public class folder
{
    public string folderName { get; set; }
    public string folderPath { get; set; }
    public List<folder> subFolders { get; set; }
}
```

as you can see the object contains an object referencing itself allowing me to build up a list of folders and sub folders, I then have a

```
List<folder> mycustomlist ect..
```

to store this in. This list can be extremely deep and works fine when binding to a treeview or custom listview.

My problem is trying to remove a nested folder from the List, I can get the object but when using

```
mycustomlist.Remove(thefolder)
```

it cant seem to locate the nested object to remove it.

I've tried several ways using Linq but with no joy, maybe their is a better way of doing this?

Hope someone can help,

Thanks

Nath

Comment: The List doesn't know it's recursive. It does not, and cannot, know what properties its items have, or what they mean. Is `theFolder` in `mycustomlist`, or in a list belonging to an item in `mycustomlist` (or a child of a child, etc.)? If you want to remove items from anywhere in this tree structure you've created, you'll have to write your own recursive method to do that.

Comment: Why do you need to find some nested objects? Your list should contain top-level folders.

Comment: Find the object containing the list which has the `folder` object you want to delete, and then delete from that point... Not from the top level...

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks, yes the thefolder exists in a child of a child. I was hoping it was clever enough but I guess I better get writing a recursive method! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Declare its parent as a property so you can remove it from its parent. `thefolder.Parent.remove(thefolder)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it cant seem to locate the nested object to remove it.

`Remove` is not recursive. It only removes an item directly in the list.

If `thefolder` is in a sublist then you'll need to recursively search for that and then remove it from the list it's actually in.

```
private bool RecursiveRemove(folder thisList, folder thefolder)
{
    if (thisList.Contains(theFolder))
    {
        thisList.Remove(theFolder);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var folder in thisList.subFolders)
        {
            if (RecursiveRemove(folder, theFolder))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;  // not found
}
```

Comment: That work first time, saved me a lot of time thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The List doesn't know it's recursive. It does not, and cannot, know what properties its items have, or what they mean. Is `theFolder` in `mycustomlist`, or in a list belonging to an item in `mycustomlist` (or a child of a child, etc.)?

If you want one function to remove a given item from *anywhere* in this tree structure you've created, regardless of which particular root or child list it lives in, you'll have to write your own recursive method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have got for this

```
    public void RemoveFolder(Folder folder, List<Folder> folderList)
    {
        if (folderList != null)
        {
            if (folderList.Contains(folder))
            {
                folderList.Remove(folder);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var subFolder in folderList.Select(x => x.subFolders))
                {
                    RemoveFolder(folder, subFolder);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

But I think you will need to write your own equity comparer

See here
[List.Contains is not working as hoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959581/list-contains-is-not-working-as-hoped)